Create a variable price calculator where more hours = more discount | Google Sheets
I want to be able to enter a single variable of 'hours' and return a result of 'price' where more hours = higher discount
Here is my sheet with the % discount:hours = price
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SprYlf8buYZ_0Pv04ZPYwzQTn4Awf-iWBj3DiNWLob4/edit?usp=sharing
How can I put this together as a simple calculator for my staff?
Example
Enter hours: 6
Return result: 7,200,000
Additionally a rounded result would be a nice feature, rounding to 100,000
Please sheet sheet for full details
TIA
I dont know where to begin with such a varibale of %

What about this formula =XLOOKUP(B27,B6:B19,D6:D19,0,1)?

I have posted the formula as answer so that you can accept (tick mark it as green) to treat the question as solved.

XLOOKUP() may help you. Try-
=XLOOKUP(B27,B6:B19,D6:D19,0,1)



to return also rounded value all in one formula, you can use:
=SORT(VLOOKUP(B27, B6:D20, {2,3}, ))


